# How to specify a user when submitting a spark job to Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

We need to submit a spark job to a mesos cluster to run as another user. Specifying --proxy-user doesn't seem to work

```
./spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster --master mesos://XXX:7077 --proxy-user userX
```

Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is see the following link:
http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/
Use the following option

```
--hostname=VALUE
```

When left empty the hostname will be resolved from the IP address. I know this is a little different compared to proxy-user

If you want to prevent the user to use the User Interface you can use ACL
https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/master/docs/security.md